# as3: youtube api / possible to add youtube's "like-button" (rating)?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, adobe

is it possible to display **youtube's like/dislike buttons** by using google's api (or any other api) for as3 ?

[image]

reference: http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html#Retrieving_video_information

Comment: I'm gonna go with no, having had a quick browse of the api docs you link to there is no mention of the like functionality :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can tie into this via the AS3 API but it looks like there are hooks for this that can return JSON data (this is known as "rating" in their system).

[API Docs for Rating](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Ratings)